# Match file in directory but not sub-directories

Tags: regex, apache, httpd.conf

I am running Apache httpd on Windows. I want to get Apache to make index.html uncacheable - but *only* the home index.html, no other index.html files. This is what I have so far:

```
<Directory "D:\path\to\root">
   <FilesMatch "index.html$">
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, must-revalidate"
   </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

It works - but works for *all* index.html files. How can I narrow this down to just the one index.html? Apparently I can use regex in Directory, but I this did not work:

```
<Directory ~ "D:\\path\\to\\root">
```

Comment: What is that last line meant to express? It certainly is no regex application...

Comment: Have you tried `^index.html$`?

Comment: @arkascha - I got that from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory - Regular expressions can also be used in the Directory tag, with the addition of the ~ character.

Comment: That documentation certainly is right, you can add RegEx evaluation that way, I did not dispute that. However the argument (the path) you specify does not really make sense as a regular expression...

Comment: AH yes, you are right - bad c&p there. I meant: <Directory ~ "D:\\path\\to\\root">.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works nicely:

```
<Location /index.html>
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, must-revalidate"
</Location>
```

Comment: Interestingly, this also works for localhost/ and localhost/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a path instead of just a file name inside the `Files` directive. So I guess the same applies to the `FilesMatch` directive. That way you could exclude files that carry a path from their subsirectory when being matched against the regular expression.

Note that I have not tested this, but it might be worth a try:

```
<Directory "D:\path\to\root">
    <FilesMatch "^[^\\]*index.html$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch >
</Directory>
```

Note that I am also not sure about which backslash (`\`) you have to escape and which not. This strange path notation MS-Windows uses internally really is a problem. Not only when dealing with regular expressions :-)

Comment: Hi Arkascha - I don't think FilesMatch or Files cares about the path. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch says "The <FilesMatch> directive limits the scope of the enclosed directives by filename, just as the <Files> directive does" and when I use <FilesMatch "^\\index.html$">, that matches localhost/index.html and localhost/second/index.html.